# Clicks on IconButton inside MUI's Select is not handled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to add a help icon inside a Select component, and would like to do something like this:

```
        <Select
            onChange={event => {
                ...
            }}
            value={mode}
            variant='outlined'
        >
            {modes.map(m => (
                <MenuItem
                    key={m.key}
                    value={m.value}
                >
                    {m.label}
                    <IconButton
                        onClick={() => {
                            alert('Clicked!')
                        }}
                    >
                        <HelpIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </MenuItem>
            ))}
        </Select>
```

I.e. I want to open the dropdown like normal when clicking the label and also be able to capture the click on the IconButton. What happens with the above code is whenever I click the IconButton, the onClick is not fired (i.e. the alert('Clicked!') is not called), and the Select dropdown opens.

Is there any way to prevent clicks on the IconButton from opening the dropdown, and only be handled by IconButton's onClick ?

See minimal example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/select-onclick-on-menuitems-button-gedusv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that seems to work is to rather handle the mouseDown event:

```
    <IconButton
      onMouseDown={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        alert("Clicked!");
      }}
    >
      <HelpIcon />
    </IconButton>
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, but seems like it does the trick

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the click event from the IconButton from bubbling up and triggering the change event of your Select component.

```
<IconButton
   onClick={(event) => {
     event.stopPropagation();
     alert('Clicked!')
   }}
>
  <HelpIcon />
</IconButton>
```

Comment: Well no, the problem isn't propagation, but rather that the IconButton's onClick event is never handled. It seems that it's stopped during the event capturing phase or something.

Comment: Could you provide a codesandbox link with minimum reproducible example of the issue?

Comment: Sure, added in OP

Comment: It seems like the opening of the dropdown is triggered by `onMouseDown` event and not the `onClick` event. So by stopping the event propagation on mouse down, we can prevent the dropdown from opening when user clicks on the icon button. Working example here: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-onclick-on-menuitems-button-forked-td2hgx?file=/index.js:613-624)

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion. It's a bit odd, but seems like the `click` event is stopped in the event capturing phase, and it therefore never reaches the children of `Select` (unless the dropdown is open). The same is not the case for the `mousedown` event luckily.